Any way to specify a Reader interface in Zig?
I'm trying to learn some basic Zig by writing a CLI app that just echoes back user input. I've got this:
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() !void {
    const stdin = std.io.getStdIn().reader();
    const stdout = std.io.getStdOut().writer();

    var buffer: [100]u8 = undefined;

    try stdout.print("Write something: ", .{});

    var input = try stdin.readUntilDelimiterOrEof(buffer[0..], '\n') orelse "";

    while (!isQuit(input)) {
        try stdout.print("You wrote '{s}'\n", .{input});
        try stdout.print("Write something else (or 'quit' to exit): ", .{});
        input = try stdin.readUntilDelimiterOrEof(buffer[0..], '\n') orelse "";
    }
}

fn isQuit(input: []const u8) bool {
    return std.mem.eql(u8, input, "quit");
}

This works fine, but I would like to be able to wrap the try stdin.readUntilDelimiter... line in a function so I can clean up the code a bit. I got the following working:
fn readInput(reader: anytype, buffer: *[100]u8) ![]u8 {
    return try reader.readUntilDelimiterOrEof(buffer[0..], '\n') orelse "";
}

I can call this as readInput(stdin, &buffer) and this works okay. However, I was wondering about two things:

Is there any way to specify that reader has to be the type returned by GenericReader? I've tried std.io.AnyReader, however, this gives me compile error.
How do I specify unknown buffer size in the argument/at the call site? fn readInput(reader: anytype, buffer: []u8) also gives compiler error if called with &buffer.

Cheers!

If you specify std.io.AnyReader as function parameter, then you need to provide one. E.g.: stdin.any() would return an AnyReader
